# Illustrator pathfinder shortcuts

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder

I constantly use the pathfinder tool and I began to wonder, is there any shortcut for this? specially for the "add shapes" function.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Illustrator does not have a default shortcut for a specific Pathfinder function. Illustrator only has a shortcut to open the Pathfinder Window.

A workaround would be to a create an action for the Pathfinder functions you use the most. Then apply a F-Key to the action.

You can also repeat a Pathfinder function by pressing CMD/CTRL + 4

Comment: I find it amazing how much of the functionality of the software is not accessible from the keyboard layout tool

Comment: Yeah I totally agree with @joojaa.
Thanks AndrewH !